# "az spring eureka-server" CLI command returns always "not found"

Tags: azure, azure-cli, netflix-eureka, azure-spring-cloud

I'm testing **Azure Spring Apps** on **Standard tier** and deployed a container image on the cluster.

But I'm not able to get info about the managed Eureka service provided by Azure Spring Apps.

The following commands are failing with no clue of the issue:

```
az spring eureka-server show -n MyCluster -g MyResourceGroup
az spring eureka-server enable -n MyCluster -g MyResourceGroup
az spring eureka-server disable -n MyCluster -g MyResourceGroup
```

All of them are returning `Operation returned an invalid status 'Not Found'`.

By using `--debug` on the commands more details are shown (the requests to Azure APIs):

```
azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: Operation returned an invalid status 'Not Found'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/glauber/.azure/cliextensions/spring/azext_spring/_utils.py", line 314, in handle_asc_exception
    raise CLIError(ex.inner_exception.error.message)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'error'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 233, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 663, in execute
    raise ex
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 726, in _run_jobs_serially
    results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy))
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 718, in _run_job
    return cmd_copy.exception_handler(ex)
  File "/home/glauber/.azure/cliextensions/spring/azext_spring/_utils.py", line 320, in handle_asc_exception
    raise CLIError(ex)
knack.util.CLIError: Operation returned an invalid status 'Not Found'

cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: Operation returned an invalid status 'Not Found'
az_command_data_logger: Operation returned an invalid status 'Not Found'
```

Is it possible that the Eureka service was not created as part of the deployment?

By running those commands in another resource groups's instance, it works.

Comment: `az spring eureka-server` cmdlets are applicable for springapps that running in Standard consumption Tier(Standard consumption & dedicated (preview)) not for standard tier and also make sure that your AzCLI is greater that 2.45.0 or higher

Comment: It was not clear on the doc that on Standard Tier (and not Standard Consumption Tier), the Eureka would be running at all times. IMO even on Standard tier the `az spring eureka-server show` command could show the details of the running Eureka server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/spring/eureka-server?view=azure-cli-latest) & said by @VenkateshDodda, it is clearly mentioned that the `az spring eureka-server` CLI command only support **Standard consumption** Tier spring app instances. As a result, when you try to get the details for the `Standard` plan app instance, it always returns a *"resource not found"* error.

Use the `az --version` command to see if your `AzCLI` version is `2.45` or higher.

[image]

After checking my `CLI` version as shown above, I've created an Azure Spring apps hosting in a `Standard Consumption` plan and tried retrieving the related information. It was successful as shown below.

[image]

```bash
az spring eureka-server show -n "spjrng" -g "xxxxx"
```

[image]